# Golang unsupported platforms

Tags: go

Golang's installation guide found at https://golang.org/doc/install has a section titled "System requirements." In this section, one of the supported operating systems is "Linux 2.6.23 or later with glibc" but it includes the following note:

> CentOS/RHEL 5.x not supported

This raises the following questions:

1. Why are these Linux distributions not supported?
2. Does this prevent users of these systems from using systems or software developed in Go?
3. Does this prevent users of these systems from developing software using Go?

Comment: 1. Lack of support for the, 2. Yes, 3. No.

Comment: What I missed when asking this question was that specific versions of these two Linux distributions were not supported. My question was based on the incorrect interpretation that these two platforms are unsupported. Well, I will still leave this question here because others who also fall into this wrong interpretation like I did, may find it helpful to get the clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These versions of Linux do not provide facilities used by the Go runtime.  See https://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/18/how-to-install-go-1-1-on-centos-5 for details.